# Raspberry Pi Model 4 - Which nonfree parts remain?

Tags: driver, gpu, bootloader, gpl-compliance

As the Raspberry Pi Model 4 was released today, I reckon it's time to update [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43489/raspberry-pi-3-usable-with-fully-free-software?noredirect=1&lq=1). I'm aware of the fact that a lot of effort was put into writing usable free software GPU drivers as stated [here](https://opensource.com/article/19/6/raspberry-pi-4):

> Over the last five years, Eric Anholt has
>   been working to write open source graphics drivers for the Raspberry
>   Pi. Now, Raspbian can use this driver to deliver accelerated web
>   browsing, desktop graphics, and 3D applications on the Pi. This
>   replaces a large chunk of closed-source code that was previously
>   required. Huge thanks to Eric and Broadcom for this effort.

What nonfree software parts remain for Raspberry Pi Model 4? Is the bootloader free at last? What about other binary blobs needed to run a Raspberry Pi Model 4?

Comment: Why did I get two downvotes for this question? Is anything wrong with it? Please elaborate.